# CXF not working after upgrading to JBoss EAP

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf, jboss7.x

We are in the process of upgrading from JBoss AS 7.3.1 to JBoss EAP 7.0. Prior to upgrading we also upgraded to Java 1.8.  After deploying our application to the new server, we are receiving the below error when starting the server.  No issues under the old JBoss server.

> org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYWS0059: Apache CXF library (cxf-bundle-2.7.12.jar) detected in ws
>   endpoint deployment; ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design as described in JIRA [WFLY-451](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-451) . You should not be packaging your own JAX-WS implementation (such as a CXF bundle) with your deployments. The JEE containers like JBoss by default implements the JAX-WS spec.

Please remove the CXF and relevant webservice jars from your application deployment. If you for some reason wish to use your own CXF jars than the ones that JBoss provides then you will need to disable the webservice subsystem in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file so that the webservice subsystem does not get activated when you deploy your application. This will also imply that you are going to support your packaged webservice implementations since it's not provided by the container out of the box.